# Saturation in magnitude estimation?

Tags: signal-power, hardware-implementation

An magnitude estimate algorithm has been used for a while in which no multiplication is done. See link here: http://dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/magnitude-estimator. This method does have advantage in terms of complexity (I know CORDIC is more accurate but too much overhead in HW). Even though the error is small in the analysis there where floating point was used, actual error rate is high when implementing in RTL fixed point. It seems adding saturation may lower actual error a bit, but not much. Just want to see if there are improvement out there.

The following code uses alpha = 1, and beta = 1/4. Average error is no way close to 0.6%.

````
module complex_to_mag #(
        parameter DATA_WIDTH = 16)
        
        (
            input                       clk,
            input                       enable,
            input                       reset,
            
            input   [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    i,
            input   [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    q,
            input                       input_strobe,
            
            output   [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]   mag,
            output  reg                     mag_strobe);
            
            
            // don't use multiplier. Just an estimator here!
            reg     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    abs_i;
            reg     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    abs_q;
            
            reg     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    max;
            reg     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    min;
            reg     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    mag_reg;
            
            // http://dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/magnitude-estimator
            // alpha = 1, beta = 1/4
            // avg err 0.006
            // This takes 3 clock cycles so need to delay mag_strobe by 3-clock from input_strobe
            always @(posedge clk) begin
                if (reset) begin
                    mag_reg <= 0;
                    abs_i <= 0;
                    abs_q <= 0;
                    max <= 0;
                    min <= 0;
                end else if (enable) begin  
                    abs_i <= i[DATA_WIDTH-1] ? (~i+1) : i;
                    abs_q <= q[DATA_WIDTH-1] ? (~q+1) : q;
                    
                    max <= abs_i > abs_q ? abs_i : abs_q;
                    min <= abs_i > abs_q ? abs_q : abs_i;
                    
                    mag_reg <= max + (min >> 2);
                end
            end
            // originally mag_reg is the output without saturation. Adding this line for saturation
            assign mag = (mag_reg[DATA_WIDTH-1]) ? {(DATA_WIDTH-1){1'b1}}: mag_reg;
            
            reg         tmp1, tmp2, tmp3;
            always @(posedge clk) begin : delay_by_3
                if (reset) begin
                    tmp1 <= 0;
                    tmp2 <= 0;
                    tmp3 <= 0;
                end else begin  
                    tmp1 <= input_strobe;
                    tmp2 <= tmp1;
                    tmp3 <= tmp2;
                    mag_strobe <= tmp3;
                end
            end
            
endmodule

// Testbench
module tb();

    reg     clk, reset, enable, input_strobe;
    reg signed [15:0]   i, q;
    
    wire signed [15:0]  mag;
    wire                mag_strobe;
    
    complex_to_mag dut(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .enable(enable), .input_strobe(input_strobe), 
                        .i(i), .q(q),
                        .mag(mag), .mag_strobe(mag_strobe));
                        
    initial begin   
        clk = 0;
        reset = 1;
        enable = 0;
        input_strobe = 0;
        count = 0;
        #100 reset = 0;
        #100 enable = 1;
    end
    
    always #20 clk = ~clk;
    
    reg signed [15:0] error;
    real       ref_mag;
    
    always @(*) begin
        ref_mag = $sqrt($itor(i)*$itor(i)+$itor(q)*$itor(q));
        if (mag_strobe) begin
            error = ref_mag - mag;
        end
    end     
    
    reg [1:0]    count;
            
    always @(posedge clk) begin 
        if (input_strobe) begin
            i <= $random;
        q <= $random;
        end 
        
        count <= count + 1;
        if (count == 3) begin
            input_strobe <= 1'b1;
            count = 0;
        end else 
            input_strobe <= 1'b0;
    end
    
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("mydumpfile.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, tb);
        #5000 $finish;
    end 
    
    real perc;
    assign perc = error / ref_mag;
    real dummy;
    assign dummy = $itor(mag);
initial begin
    $monitor("mag_strobe= %d, mag = %d, ref_mag = %d, error = %d, percentage = %f", mag_strobe, dummy, ref_mag, error, perc);
    end
    
endmodule
```
````

Answer (score -1):

> Average error is no way close to 0.6%.

Why would it be? Even the most casual inspection shows that the error will much bigger.

Let's look at a simple 45 degree angle. Let's assume $z = 1 + i$ and so $|z| = \sqrt{2}$.

The algorithm would estimate this as $|z|' = 1 + 0.25 = 1.25$, which is off by about 11.6% or -18.7dB, which is what the author quoted.

Comment: I don't think you had actually opened the link in my post and checked the table there. The C code in the link implemented differently than the RTL I coded. The question is how to improve the error rate.

Comment: The 0.6% is grossly misleading. Technically, it's the average error and it's small, but only because half of the error is positive and half is negative.  You only get errors that small if the phase angle is either 0 or 22.5 degrees. You probably want to look at the mean of the absolute error instead. I don't think your issue has anything to do with fixed point, it's related to the algorithm itself. What specific error metric do you care about ?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to approximate the magnitude of a complex number $Z=I+jQ$ with a linear formula:

$$|Z| \approx \alpha  \max(|I|, |Q|) + \beta \min(|I|, |Q|)$$

It looks a lot to me as standard diagonal approximations found in engineer books, before the spread of electronic calculators. For instance in  "Notes et formules de l'ingénieur of De Laharpe" (my 1923 edition below)

[image: "Notes et formules de l'ingénieur of De Laharpe" (my 1923 edition)]

you fget the approximation, for $a>b>0$:

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=0.96a+0.40b$$

[image: "Notes et formules de l'ingénieur of De Laharpe" square root approximation]

with an error of about 4%. I checked this was correct in my youth, and the $\alpha $ and $\beta $ where well-chosen (if I remember well). On the diagonal ($I=Q$) you reach $(1.41-1.36)/1.41 \approx 0.36$, but here you have a much simpler linear  formula: $|I+jI|=\sqrt{2}I$.
Those values are indeed provided in your link:

```
Min RMS Err      0.947543636291 0.392485425092   0.000547 -32.6 -25.6
```

but the average value given should depend  on the sampling of the half-quadrant.
In the following, I generated all the ordered pairs of integers $\{I,Q\}$, code with $b$ bits: $2^b-1\ge I>Q>0$, with $b=12$. Then I computed the absolute relative error:

$$e(a,b) = \frac{|\sqrt{I^2+Q^2}-\alpha I-\beta Q|}{\sqrt{I^2+Q^2}}\,. $$

Then, I estimated the optimal $(\alpha,\beta)$ to get (step-size of $1/100$), respectively, the minimum:

- mean relative error (1.97%) with $(0.9293,0.4242)$,
- median relative error (0.68%) with $(0.8182,0.5859)$,
- maximum relative error (4.12%) with $(0.9596,0.4040)$

on a relatively coarse  $(\alpha,\beta)$ grid. Hence the above numbers don't have 4-digit precision. With finer confidence intervals, one gets:

- mean relative error (1.97%) with $(0.9281-0.9288,0.0.4212-0.4235)$,
- median relative error (0.65%) with $(0.8160-0.8167,0.5876-0.5899)$,
- maximum relative error (3.96%) with $(0.9601-0.9608,0.3965-0.3988)$.

Of course, you will probably round those values, and get a larger error.

Comment: right, the simulation result in the link showed about 0.6% error rate, which I verified. But this error rate is impossible to have in fixed point implementation (see my code where a 16-bit number was used).

Comment: I think 16-bit is small enough (and finite), so you could derive your own affine factors for your specific fixed point inputs

Comment: I guess you meant 16-bit is small in terms of resolution? Actually using 16-bit is very expensive in HW because there will be very expensive ADCs to get these 16-bit numbers. Usually just 12-bit ADCs are used.

Comment: No, I am not skill in dealing with fixed-point. I mean that you can exhaustively compute the error for each integer pair $(I,Q)$ in $[0:2^b-1,0:2^b-1]$.

Comment: I have updated the results, with finer intervals